# Getting a null intent with onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is the code from the MainActivity that calls the intent:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNote.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
```

It then goes to the NewNote class which does this with the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("title", title.getText().toString());

                //set the result, it will be passed to onActivityResult() in MainActivity
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
```

Finally, inside the MainActivity I have the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("title");
            //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the OnActivityResult method works fine however the output by the value variable is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

To:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours haha. I will click the check mark as soon as it lets me.